# How to define user models with multiple access level in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, organization

How can a user be a member of multiple organizations and have different roles in each organization, depending on what level of access they need.

Comment: I just want someone who may help me figure out, how to structure my django models

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this [build_user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-custom-user-model), you can use it as it comes by default or you can customize [custom_user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/) it so that you can accept a more specific authentication [authentication_user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/), in addition to defining the user model or extending the permission control, you define it in the View by validating user permissions with (request .user.username), I hope it serves you, greetings.

Comment: Thank you John, I already have a custom user model, and an organization model, I now want users to have differentes role in differentes organizations